# Set outgoing packet ip address on machine with multiple ip addresses

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, httpurlconnection

I'm writing an application that has 10 (as an Example) threads running. each thread creates a connection using `HttpURLConnection` to external host. I need to use a different IP address for each connection in different threads. can I do it considering the fact that there are about 10 valid static IP addresses assigned to my server?

note that I have seen something like same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466677/many-ip-addresses-on-machine-set-outgoing-ip-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376634/how-can-i-tell-java-to-use-a-specific-outgoing-ip-interface-for-a-http-request) but in first one though it has an answer checked as correct by asker, but I see too many comments telling that Its not working and in second one is talking about *How to make the JVM use a given source IP by default?* which does not help me I guess.

beside I don't want to risk and pay for the server and then find out I cant do such a thing!

Comment: Attach them as different interfaces, it'd work.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful would you please provide some code to let me know how can I do it?